# Multiple actions were found: /resource/id vs /resource/id/action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I realize this is a common question, but I can't find one that properly asks the same question with my configuration.

I have a default route that looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
public class VariablesController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Variable> Get()
    {
        // get all
    }

    public Variable Get( int id )
    {
        // get individual
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public DistributionReport GetDistribution( int id )
    {
        // get distribution report
    }
}
```

When I `GET /api/variables/1/getDistribution`, it works fine.

When I `GET /api/variables/1`, I get a 500 exception:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>      Models.Variable Get(Int32) on type Controllers.Api.VariablesController
>      Models.DistributionReport GetDistribution(Int32) on type Controllers.Api.VariablesController

What do I need to do to modify my situation so they both work?

Comment: Are you using Web API 2? if yes, i would recommend using the in-built attribute routing to solve this easily. As for the exception, its expected because Web API is unable to decide which action to select based on the the current request's(`GET /api/variables/1`) information.

Comment: @KiranChalla I fully understand WHY this is happening, but HOW do I fix it?  What "in-built attribute routing" are you speaking of?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: @KiranChalla I'm still looking for HOW to fix it.  I've tried using the Route attribute (I'm using WebApi 2.0). (https://gist.github.com/BrianGenisio/7793430)  I don't get the multiple routes error, but when I `GET /api/variables/10`, it routes to the `GetDistribution` action. (`GET /api/variables/10/getDistribution` gets routed properly. )

Comment: I tried with your controller now and I am unable to repro your scenario...

Comment: would it possible for you to share a simple repro...i will be glad to take a look at it...but from the given controller, i tried a very simple scenario and it doesn't repro the issue you are mentioning...since you have an explicit literal in the path of GetDistribution action, i am not sure why would webapi route to it when the request is `GET /api/variables/10`...something else must be going on i think..

Comment: @KiranChalla I created a repo, and I can't reproduce the problem either.  Now I need to do some searching.

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  I wasn't calling `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` in my `WebApiConfig.Register` function. So, that plus `[Route("api/variables/{id}")]` on the `Get(int id)` action was all I needed to disambiguate the two.  If you write it up in an answer, I'll give you your 25 pts :)

Comment: That's OK :)...just FYI...conventional routes matching requests will never see any attributed controller/actions.